# 3 tables in one mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am in need of some help with my mysql query code! I have three data bases and I am trying to find a way to post data from all three.

```html
users
----------------------------------
user_id   username      email..etc
-----------------------------------
1         username
-----------------------------------


friends_db
-------------------------------------
user_id   friend_id   friend_active
--------------------------------------
   1          2               1
--------------------------------------


posts
-------------------------------------
post_id   user_id      post_content
-------------------------------------
1         1             this is a post
--------------------------------------
```

What I would like to do is make an friends post list where you can see all the posts that your friends (those who have a 1 in friend_active) have done.

my function:

```
function getFriendsPosts()
{   

    require "config.php";

    $friends = $c->query ( "SELECT * FROM friends_db WHERE user_id=" . $_SESSION["user_id"] ." AND friend_active = 1" ) ; 

    if ( $friends->num_rows > 0 ) 
    {

        while( $row = $friends->fetch_assoc() ) 
        {
            $postData[] = array( "user_id" => $row[ "user_id" ], "friend_active" => $row[ "friend_active" ], "friend_id" => $row[ "friend_id" ] );
        }
    } else {
        echo "No Data To Show";
    }

    return $postData;

}
```

I have:

```
$friends = $c->query ( "SELECT * FROM friends_db WHERE user_id=" . $_SESSION["user_id"] ." AND friend_active = 1" ) ;
```

which gives me the user_id of anyone who has friend_active = 1

however I do not know how to expand this by relating friend_id with their own user_id to get their username in which will then also get their posts to show.

I may be over complicating this or I may not be, I do not know. 
Does anyone know how I can do this in the same format that I have done already (I have other things working on this format and I need this to be too)? Or perhaps has some advice?

**Edit:**

```
$friends = getFriendsPosts();

foreach ($friends as $friend) {
    ?>
    <div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
    <div id="searchpost">
    <?php 


    echo $friend['user_id']; 
    echo $friend['friend_id']; 
    echo $friend['friend_active'];


    ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
}
?>
```

Id like to:

echo username (in relation to friend_id/thier own user ID)
echo post data (in relation to user_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the `friends_db` part of your query is actually the `friends` table?I am also assuming there is a relationship between these tables:

If so, you can use a join:

```
select * from friends as f
join users as u on u.user_id = f.user_id 
join posts as p on p.user_id = f.user_id
where f.user_id = ...
```

Alternatively, to get YOUR FRIENDS' POST:

```
select * from posts as p
join users as u on u.user_id = p.user_id //gets users table where related to posts
join friends as f on f.user_id = p.user_id //gets friends where related 
join users as fu on fu.user_id = f.friend_id //gets users table where related to friend user_id 
where u.user_id = ....//the sources user_id
```

Comment: Aye, I am trying to display posts (in posts database) made by users(in users database ) that are your friends (in friends database).I could put the username in with the friends database to narrow it down to two tables to access, but I am having trouble joining two databases together anyway. I am not too familiar with the code you gave me could you explain it to me so I may add onto it for the posts database? Thank you :)

Comment: see edits. This is sort of a vague question in hindsight. You post made by friends of a particular id right?

Comment: Edited with what I have on my index to post. :)